# ERROR: Expected ";" in VS Code (using a macro)

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(x, y) do { typeof(x) SWAP = x; x = y; y = SWAP; } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    printf("======[ Swap algorithm ]======\n\n"
           "» Values before swap:\n\t"
           "A -> %d\n\t"
           "B -> %d", 
           a, b);
    SWAP(a, b); // <---- Warning here, expected ";".
    return 0;
}
```

This works pretty well in CLion but not in VS Code, I don't now why.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What compiler are you using with CLion? What compiler are you using with VSCode?

Comment: Compile with `-E` to see the output from preprocessor to see what you're actually compiling

Comment: Do you get the error when compiling, or only in the IDE's error reporting?

Comment: `typeof(x)` is a compiler-specific extension. VS code (or the compiler it invoked) must not be familiar with it which causes the error.

Comment: [typeof](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) is part of Gnu gcc. Otherwise it looks like a function call not ending in `;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `SWAP` is not an invocation of a function-like macro so it won't be expanded. And macros aren't invoked recursively in any case.

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, please copy-paste (as text!) the *full* and *complete* build output into the question.

Comment: @interjay: Only the IDE's report, from the beginning it compiled but VSCode kept warning me. The solution I found was to add a settings.json in my .vscode folder (I'm using the C/C++ Microsoft extension) with this code: `{ "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled" }` .To be honest, I don't really know if that's the right thing to do, but now it compiles without any warning and swaps the values just how I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Because MSVC compiler does not support `typeof` extension.
Logs from [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hf5xPPPPf):

```
<source>(12): error C3861: 'typeof': identifier not found
<source>(12): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'SWAP'
<source>(12): error C2065: 'SWAP': undeclared identifier
```

Hopefully it may have start to support it. Because a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2685.htm) for C23 standard it likely to be merged.

---

For now, you can use a workaround with `memcpy()` trick.

```
#define SWAP(x, y)               \
do {                             \
  char SWAP[sizeof x];           \
  memcpy(SWAP, &x, sizeof SWAP); \
  x = y;                         \
  memcpy(&y, SWAP, sizeof SWAP); \
} while (0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll start to use this when I work with the MSVC compiler.